# Returning True or False on Prepared Statements

Tags: php, mysqli

I just started learning mysqli (20 minutes ago) and I'm confused on something. In the example below I'm able to insert data into the server. How would I make the function return true on success and false on failure. Is it as simple as replacing `return true` on if the if statement is true and `return false` on the else statement or is it more advanced than that? What would I have to write if I wanted to return true on success and false on failure?

```
function insert($firstName, $lastName) {
   if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO CodeCall (FirstName, LastName) values (?, 

   ?)")) {

/* Bind our params */
$stmt->bind_param('ss', $firstName, $lastName);


/* Execute the prepared Statement */
$stmt->execute();

/* Echo results */
echo "Inserted {$lastName},{$firstName} into database\n";

/* Set our params for second query */
$firstName = "John";
$lastName  = "Ciacia";

/* Execute second Query */
$stmt->execute();

    return true;

/* Close the statement */
$stmt->close(); 
    }
    else {
/* Error */
return false;
    }}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you execute your INSERT query (also UPDATES and DELETES queries) using execute method, it returns TRUE on success and FALSE on failure.
So you could do something like this:

```
function insert($firstName, $lastName) {
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO CodeCall (FirstName, LastName) values (?, ?)");

    /* Bind our params */
    $stmt->bind_param('ss', $firstName, $lastName);

    /* Execute the prepared Statement */
    if ( $stmt->execute() ) {
        /* Echo results */
        echo "Inserted {$lastName},{$firstName} into database\n";

        /* Set our params for second query */
        $firstName = "John";
        $lastName  = "Ciacia";

        /* Execute second Query */
        $stmt->execute();

        $result = true;
    } else {
        /* Error */
        $result = false;
    }

    /* Close the statement */
    $stmt->close(); 

    return $result;
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't I need to bind the result to the variable `$result`?

Comment: Of course you can. I did it that way to show you how you can easily put the execute call in an IF condition.